# java queue exception class

Tags: java, queue

I'm writing a queue class and have already written the interface and queue class and have been instructed to write an exception class that handles both an empty and a full exception. When our class did a stack program we had separate classes for both StackFullException and StackEmptyException which I understood how to write but I don't really understand how to combine it into one QueueException class.

This is what I have so far

```
public class QueueException extends Exception {


     public QueueEmptyException() {
         super("Stack is empty");
     }

     public QueueFullException() {
         super("Stack is full");
     }

     public QueueException(String msg) {
         super(msg);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close!  It would be a good idea to split them up into multiple classes such as `QueueEmptyException` and `QueueFullException`, but if you *really* want to combine them into a single class, then you only require a single constructor:

```
public class QueueException extends Exception {
    public QueueException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

When you want to throw this exception, you can call either of the two:

```
throw new QueueException("Queue is full!");
throw new QueueException("Queue is empty!");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use inheritance.

So create a new class `QueueException`:

```
public class QueueException extends Exception {
    public QueueException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

and let your `QueueEmptyException` and `QueueFullException` inherit from `QueueException` instead of `Exception`

```
public class QueueEmptyException extends QueueException{

   public QueueEmptyException() {
     super("Queue is empty");
   }
}
```

in the method that actually throws the exception you can do the following:

```
public void someMethodThrowingQueueExceptions() throws QueueException{
  //some logic
  //throw here either a full or empty exception
  throw new QueueEmptyException();
}
```